# Why can't we change data pointer of std::vector?

Tags: c++, c++17, stdvector

I have an array `char* source` and a vector `std::vector<char> target`. I'd like to make the vector `target` point to `source` in O(1), without copying the data.

Something along these lines:

```
#include <vector>

char* source = new char[3] { 1, 2, 3 };
std::vector<char> target;
target.resize(3);

target.setData(source); // <- Doesn't exist
// OR
std::swap(target.data(), source); // <- swap() does not support char*
delete[] source;
```

Why is it not possible to manually change where a vector points to? Is there some specific, unmanageable problem that would arise if this was possible?

Comment: What would happen to size and capacity if you just swapped in some random pointer?

Comment: Rust has this as [`Vec::from_raw_parts`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.from_raw_parts), C++ has no equivalent. Why do you want this? Is there a reason you cannot fill a vector directly with the data? Otherwise, unique_ptr<T[]> is closer to what you have (and, if C++ ever supported this, would be the thing it accepts during construction).

Comment: @RetiredNinja That's definitely something to worry about. I would say, however, that C++ is not stranger to having to deal with potentially destructive memory stuff. In my example, I first resized the vector.

Comment: Not only size and capacity, how should `std::vector` delete that pointer? With `delete` or `delete[]`? And what if a custom allocator was specified for `std::vector`?

Comment: `std::vector_view` (hypothetical)?

Comment: There is [`span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span); I never used it because it's in C++20, but it looks like the correct class to use.

Comment: @Antti_M -- Create your own `std::span` class.  As the previous comment suggested, that is basically what you want to accomplish -- you want all of the functionality of `std::vector` without resizing or memory management.

Comment: frame challenge : As long as you control the allocation (incl. re-allocation and de-allocation) for `source` in your original code, typically, this can be done the other way around : `std::vector<char> v(N, '\0'); char* source = v.data(); /* fill source */`.

Comment: For one thing, `target.setData(source);` uses camelCase for the function name, and the standard never does that. <g>

Comment: @Antti_M *Why can't we change data pointer of std::vector?* -- Assume you could do this -- what happens here?  `int *ptr = (int *)GlobalAlloc(50);` -- The `GlobalAlloc` function is a Windows API function that allocates memory.  What do you think will happen if you gave `ptr` to `std::vector` to handle?  Sparks will be flying out your computer.

Answer (score 7):

C++ `vector` class supports adding and deleting elements, with guaranteed consecutive order in memory. If you could initialize your `vector` with existing memory buffer, and add enough elements to it, it would either overflow or require reallocation.

The interface of `vector` assumes that it *manages* its internal buffer, that is, it can allocate, deallocate, resize it whenever it wants (within spec, of course). If you need something that is not allowed to *manage* its buffer, you cannot use `vector` - use a different data structure or write one yourself.

You can create a `vector` object by copying your data (using a constructor with two pointers or `assign`), but this is obviously not what you want.

Alternatively, you can use [`string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/string_view), which looks almost or maybe exactly what you need.

Comment: That's what a vector has to do anyways, right? In this use case, you would have to of course resize the vector first, but after that I don't see a problem.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "that"; anyway, you are trying to take away from `vector` something that it wants to support (reallocation); in your use-case this may make sense, but in general this is not supported by the language.

Comment: @Antti_M If you resize the vector, it internally allocates memory. It does not make sense then to throw this memory away and replace it with an externally provided buffer.

Answer (score 3):

`std::vector` is considered to be the owner of the underlying buffer. You can change the buffer but this change causes allocation i.e. making a copy of the source buffer which you don't want (as stated in the question).

You could do the following:

```cpp
#include <vector>

int main() {
    char* source = new char[3] { 1, 2, 3 };
    std::vector<char> target;
    target.resize(3);
    target.assign(source, source + 3);
    delete[] source;
    return 0;
}
```

but again [`std::vector::assign`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign):

> Replaces the contents with **copies** of those in the range [first, last).

So copy is performed again. You can't get away from it while using `std::vector`.

If you don't want to copy data, then you should use `std::span` from C++20 (or create your own span) or use `std::string_view` (which looks suitable for you since you have an array of `char`s).

**1st option: Using `std::string_view`**

Since you are limited to C++17, `std::string_view` might be perfect for you. It constructs a view of the first 3 characters of the character array starting with the element pointed by `source`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

int main() {
    char* source = new char[3] { 1, 2, 3 };

    std::string_view strv( source, 3 );

    delete[] source;

    return 0;
}
```

**2nd option: Using `std::span` from C++20**

`std::span` comes from C++20 so it might not be the most perfect way for you, but you might be interested in what it is and how it works. You can think of `std::span` as a bit generalized version of `std::string_view` because it is a contiguous sequence of objects of any type, not just characters. The usage is similar as with the `std::string_view`:

```cpp
#include <span>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    char* source = new char[3] { 1, 2, 3 };

    std::span s( source, 3 );

    delete[] source;

    return 0;
}
```

**3rd option: Your own span**

If you are limited to C++17, you can think of creating your own `span` struct. It might still be an overkill but let me show you (btw take a look at this more elaborated [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60151658/5517378)):

```cpp
template<typename T>
class span {
   T* ptr_;
   std::size_t len_;

public:
    span(T* ptr, std::size_t len) noexcept
        : ptr_{ptr}, len_{len}
    {}

    T& operator[](int i) noexcept {
        return *ptr_[i];
    }

    T const& operator[](int i) const noexcept {
        return *ptr_[i];
    }

    std::size_t size() const noexcept {
        return len_;
    }

    T* begin() noexcept {
        return ptr_;
    }

    T* end() noexcept {
        return ptr_ + len_;
    }
};

int main() {
    char* source = new char[3] { 1, 2, 3 };

    span s( source, 3 );

    delete[] source;

    return 0;
}
```

So the usage is the same as with the C++20's version of `std::span`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, I was not really struggling to work around this. Instead, I was interested in precicely what I asked: Why can we not change the underlying pointer? Upvoted, but not quite the accepted answer I was looking for. :)

Answer (score -1):

The std::string_view and std::span are good things to have (if you have compiler version supporting them). Rolling your own similars is ok too.

But some people miss the whole point why one would want to do this exactly to a vector:

- Because you have an **API that gives** `Struct[]` + `size_t` and give you ownership
- and you also have an **API that accepts** `std::vector<Struct>`

ownership could be easily transferred into the vector and no copies made!

You can say: But what about custom allocators, memory mapped file pointers, rom memory that I could then set as the pointer?

- If you are already about to set vector internals you should know what you are doing.
- You can try to supply a "correct" allocator in those cases to your vector actually.

Maybe give a warning on compiling this code yes, but it would be nice if it would be possible.

I would do it this way:

- `std::vector` would get a constructor that asks for a `std::vector::raw_source`
- `std::vector::raw_source` is an `uint8_t*, size_t, bool` struct (for now)
- `bool takeOwnership`: tells if we are taking ownership (false => copy)
- `size_t size`: the size of the raw data
- `uint8_t* ptr`: the pointer to raw data
- When taking ownership, vector resize and such uses the vectors allocation strategy as you otherwise provided with your template params anyways - nothing new here. If that does not fit the data you are doing wrong stuff!

Yes API I say look more complicated than a single "set_data(..)" or "own_memory(...)" function, but tried to make it clear that anyone who ever uses this api pretty much understands implications of it automagically. I would like this API to exists, but maybe I still overlook other causes of issues?