# Is it possible to move a vector into a vector of different type?

Tags: c++, stdvector, move-semantics

Assume, I have two functions that work with arguments that are vectors of different types:

```
void foo(const std::vector<SomeType>& v);
void bar(const std::vector<std::byte>& v);
```

What if in some place of my code I want to pass the same vector object to both of these functions? Obviously, I cannot just cast a vector of one type to a vector of different type, so I have to create a second vector:

```
const std::vector<SomeType> v(...);
foo(v);
// v is not needed anymore
const auto vSizeBytes = v.size() * sizeof(SomeType);
std::vector<std::byte> v2;
v2.resize(vSizeBytes);
std::memcpy(&v2[0], &v[0], vSizeBytes);
bar(v2);
```

But if I know for sure that `v` is not needed anymore after calling `foo(v)`, I want move instead of copy. Is there any alternative to `std::memcpy()` for moving the original data of a container into another container instead of copying it?

Comment: No there's no "move" possible. And besides, unless `SomeType` is a POD-like structure you can't use `memcpy` either.

Comment: You can move elements from one container to another, but the element type of the destination container must be constructible by an xvalue of the element type of the source container.  That does not seem to be the case here, and is not generically.

Comment: If you are on C++20, you could use a [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) as a "view" of the `v.data()` of the `vector<SomeType>`, cast to `std::byte const*` with the calculated extent.  See this longer explanation (and C++11 alternative): https://stackoverflow.com/a/60151658/4641116

Comment: Sorry, but C++ simply doesn't work this way.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It looks like you want to reinterpret each item in the vector as its underlying byte representation. This is possible. No need to copy.

Comment: @JohnFilleau, How can I cast, let's say a vector of `int`'s, to a vector of `std::byte`'s?

Comment: @Alexey104 look at the link in Eljay's comment. You wouldn't be casting the `vector<int>` to a `vector<byte>`. You'd be casting each `int&` as a `byte&` or `byte[sizeof(int)]`.

Comment: You likely also have an XY problem. You want to ultimately achieve one thing, X, and you think you need to do Y to accomplish it. So you only ask about Y. If I had to guess you're trying to serialize a vector of ints (for archiving or transmission) and you think making a completely new vector of bytes is the way to go.

Comment: Do you *have to* use the function signatures you presented? If you have to use the same data for both things, I think what you could really use is to change the function signature of `bar` to take a `uint8_t*` and a `size_t`.

Comment: I actually need to call a legacy C function that accepts an array of `unsigned char*` as argument. `bar()` is a function that eventually call this legacy function inside itself passing the underlying vector data to it. The data is stored as `std::vector<std::byte>`, but in one specific place in my code I want to pass an already existing vector of `int`'s to `bar()` as a vector of `std::byte`'s.

Comment: I think `std::span` might be what I am looking for. Thank you, @Eljay!

Answer (score 0):

You can use templates. Assuming the code in the function will work on both types.

```
template<class SOMETYPE> void foo(const std::vector<SOMETYPE>& v);
template<class SOMETYPE> void bar(const std::vector<SOMETYPE>& v);
```